# Allocation of double struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have the following Hash_table and Hash_bucket structs

```
typedef struct Hash_Table{
   struct Bucket** bucket;
}Table;

typedef struct Bucket{
   struct Bucket* next;
   int num;
}Bucket;
```

I want to allocate 5 Hash Tables which i do like this,

```
Table** hash_tables = malloc(sizeof(Table*)* 5);
for(int i = 0; i <=4 ; i++){
  hash_tables[i] = NULL;
}
```

To my knowledge, what I have done up to here is correct, and I want to proceed allocating the Hash Tables in my code. As i did with the double pointer above, my allocation for the Hash Table

```
hash_table[0] = malloc(sizeof(Table));
hash_table[0]->bucket = malloc(sizeof(Bucket*)*10);  /* line 2 that is problematic*/
```

I allocate the size for a Hash_Table and then 10 Hash_Bucket pointers. However, I am having leaks and **NOT** because I free the memory wrongly. The **line 2** of the allocation seems to be redundant (?) and if I replace the Hash_Table with

```
typedef struct Hash_Table{
   struct Bucket* bucket[10];
}Table;
```

, then the line 2 is not needed, everything works perfect and memory is free'd. I really am clueless as to what I am doing wrong. I've found the mistake, but don't see the mistake in the first place. Thank you all.

Comment: "*I am having leaks*". How are you determining that? "*NOT because I free the memory wrong"*". How can you be sure about that since by definition you are here because you don't know where the problem is? We need to be able to see that code to verify. Please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: Why do you think that this "line 2" is redundant? Where else do you allocate your `Hash_Bucket` pointer array?

Comment: what is `struct Bucket`? `struct Hash_Table` doesn't have a member called `hash_buckets`.

Comment: JamesTheProg, Try compiling `hash_table[0]->hash_buckets`.  There is no member `.hash_buckets`.  Post a [mcve].  Also review `hash_table[0]->hash_buckets = malloc(sizeof(Hash_Bucket*)*10);` --> What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah I changed some of the variable names to make it simpler, my bad on that. Program compiles and runs. What I am doing in that allocation is allocating the "struct Bucket** bucket" struct member. Allocating an array for 10 Buckets*, 10 pointers to buckets from 0-9 for the array bucket[i].

Comment: Please post a C [mcve] that demos "I am having leaks".  _Talking_ about code is good only is true compliable C code included.

Comment: There is no type `Hash_Table` to support `Hash_Table** hash_tables = [...]`. There would be if the code were compiled as C++, but then it would be required to cast the result of `malloc()`.  And it is important to be clear about whether you are writing C or C++, and to instruct your tools appropriately about that.  These are distinct languages, neither a subset of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Code you posted without the "line 2 is redundant" part should look like this right:

```
typedef struct Bucket {
struct Bucket* next;
int num;
} Bucket;
    
typedef struct Hash_Table {
struct Bucket** bucket;
} Table;
    
int main(void)
{
// Create hashtable
Table** hash_tables = malloc(sizeof(Table*) * 5);
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
hash_tables[i] = NULL;
}
    
// Create Bucket
hash_tables[0] = malloc(sizeof(Table));
hash_tables[0]->bucket = malloc(sizeof(Bucket*)*10); /* line 2 that is problematic*/
    
free(hash_tables[0]->bucket);
free(hash_tables[0]);
free(hash_tables);
return 0;
}
```

If you add the right free's at the bottom you shouldn't have memory leaks.
At least [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) says so.

Note: for every written `malloc` in your code, you need at least 1 `free`